# Using 1 int to send 2 numbers

Tags: c

I am working with a system whereby I can send 1 32 bit int at a time.  However I need to send two numbers at a time.  What is the best way to do this in standard C?

I assume I will have to do some conversion to binary/hex and some masking?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: A union would be one easy way to do this.

Comment: @David: No, unions store only one thing at a time.

Comment: What is the range of each number? How many bits do you need to send each number?

Comment: Do you mean "send over a network" or "send from one part of my program to another"? What's the range of possible values of the numbers you want to pack into a single 32-bit integer?

Comment: @delnan Hmm, I'm sure you can put one thing in and take a different thing out. Not portable I know.

Comment: what is the size of the numbers you want to send? 16 bits or less?

Comment: @delnan, I think David H. meant a union containing an int and a struct.

Comment: (But note that a union-with-struct solution is no good if you need to send these things over a network, because the recipient might do its struct-packing differently.)

Comment: "The system" isn't likely to take kindly to any attempt to encode two numbers in one 32-bit int.  You are going to have to change the system too.  Which leaves plenty of opportunity to fix the problem in a decent way.

Comment: Well, one might guess that OP wants to pack 2 16 bit integers in a single 32 bit integer.

Comment: @Joe - I have no specified size.  I'll make do with whatever I can get.

Comment: @Gareth: He did? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question, but I think it's "how do I put two shorts in a int", not "how do I sometimes have an int and sometimes two shorts".

Comment: @Ferguzz You need a specific range or size to make sure your two values will safely fit into the 32 bit container. Think of it as liquid. You could pour 24 oz in one zip lock bag and 8 oz into a different zip log bag, and ship them in 1, 32oz container

Comment: @delnan, sorry if I wasn't clear; I was taking David H. to be saying: "to fit two shorts in a long, say union { long a; struct { short b,c; } }, then store into b,c and take out a or vice versa". (Of course if he'd been saying it carefully he'd have said it more carefully, using bitfields or (compiler-dependent) struct-packing directives or whatever. And I make no claim that this is actually the best approach; I'd probably do it with bit-twiddling logical ops, myself.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can encode two 16-bit *unsigned* numbers like this:

```
unsigned int out = (in1 << 16) | in2;
```

and decode them like this:

```
unsigned int in1 = out >> 16;
unsigned int in2 = out & 0xFFFF;
```

All this assumes that `int` is at least 32 bits, that `in1` and `in2` are in the 0-65535 range, and that an `unsigned int` can be sent across correctly (w.r.t. endianness).

Comment: That works as long as the sender and receiver have the same endianess. If that's going "on the wire", care must be taken (i.e. see the `htons` family of functions).

Comment: +1 But the +1 should go to Mat, because his caveat is more important than your solution (that is good too)... And perhaps you could explain that with "signed" ints all bets are off (because shift is undefined with integer < 0 )

Comment: The only data types I have at my disposal are int (32) and float (32) but i'll have a go now at making something like this work.  Thanks!

Comment: endianess - a word I'm going to try and get into as many conversations as possible this week, for sport. :)

Comment: +1, if "the system" that already exists can sent a 32 bit int correctly, then it already accounts for endian-ness, and therefore this code will work regardless of the endian-ness of the sender or the recipient. If the existing system doesn't deal with endian-ness correctly, then that's a problem, but not with this answer. I suppose there's a slight niggle that this code doesn't work if the channel only does *signed* int, and the sending C implementation can't convert large unsigned values to signed. You'd create your unsigned int for sending, and now what? But that's rather rare.

Comment: This seems to work fine just using regular ints.  Under what conditions would it break?

Comment: If the sender and the receiver use different endianness (which is spelled with three n's), the two ints will be swapped *and* their bytes will be reversed.

Comment: @Mat: Endianness doesn't matter for bit shifting, only for reading/writing.

Answer (score 2):

If the numbers you are sending are between 0 and 65535 each just pack them in the 32-bit int you can send:

```
unsigned int n1 = 42;
unsigned int n2 = 1600;
unsigned int numbertosend = (n1 << 16) | n2;
```

On the receiving side, unpack the number

```
unsigned int n1 = receivednumber >> 16;
unsigned int n2 = receivednumber & 0xFFFF;
```

Answer (score 1):

What range are your numbers? If they can fit in 16 bits, then you can pack two of those in your 32 bit int. Something like `i = (n1 << 16) | (n2 &0xffff)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could encode 2 16-bit numbers into a 32-bit number.
For example:

```
int32 encode(int16 numA, int16 numb) {
    int 32 result = numA << 16 | numB;
    return  result;
}

int16 decodeNum1(int32 num) {
    return (num >> 16) & 0xFFFF;
}

int16 decodeNum2(int32 num) {
    return (num) & 0xFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the two numbers you want to send are both prime, you could multiply them and send the product, and on the server factor them to get the result.

;p  (inspired by the ambiguity in the question)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to send 2 16-bit numbers, you could probably do something like this:

```
unsigned int a, b, toSend;
// Give a and b a value...
toSend = ( a << 16 ) | b;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [Unions in c](http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/c-language/c-structures-and-unions.html)
would do the job.You could also go for [Bit Fields in C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field)